# Matrix Theory approach to general Linear Equations over skew fields

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a matrix way of writing system of linear equation over a skew field where the variables in the equations are both left multiplied and right multiplied by elements of the skew fields.
Is the complexity of solving such equations ( say over the quaternions) known.

Comment: If your skew field is a finite dimensional algebra over a commutative field (as e.g. the quaternions) then using a basis will quickly reduce your question to standard linear algebra.

Comment: Almost everything known about linear equations over general skew fields can be found in the book by P. M. Cohn, "Skew Fields", Cambridge University Press, 1995.